# Compiling coffeescript test with the npm module

Tags: coffeescript, npm

Is it possible to compile a string of coffeescript with the npm module, I have been looking everywhere and cannot seem to find any good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coffee-script module provides a "compile" method:

```
var cs = require('coffee-script');
var js = cs.compile('foo = -> "bar"');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the `coffee` command line utility, then yes you can (although it isn't too pretty):

```
echo "alert 'Hello World'" | coffee -sc
```

The code above compiles the CoffeeScript in the echo and outputs to STDOUT. If you want the compiled output in a file, you can do this:

```
echo "alert 'Hello World'" | coffee -sc > path/to/file.js
```

There's some good documentation on the command-line utility here: http://coffeescript.org/#usage

If you mean compiling a string *within* CoffeeScript code, the `coffee-script` module provides a compile function:

```
coffee = require 'coffee-script'
js = coffee.compile "alert 'Hello World'"
```